# how to make language specific keybinding in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to make a keybinding in vscode, but want it to only work in markdown. I think I should use `when` clause, but not sure how to set the parameter for this clause.

Comment: Visual Studio Code Key Bindings
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_conditional-operators

when clause contexts | Visual Studio Code Extension API
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-context-keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the `editorLangId` parameter in the `when` condition key.
You should do something like this:

```json
{
"key": "key1+key2+key3",
"command": "some.editor.action",
"when": "editorLangId == 'markdown' && withThisCondition || otherwiseSomethingElse"
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me! `[{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f5",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "when": "editorLangId == 'javascript'",
    "args": { "text": "echo 'a'\u000D" }
}]`